# Headless Chrome 79 does not load fonts from Google Fonts on Windows

Tags: google-chrome, font-face, google-chrome-headless, google-font-api

I have a problem with external font-face loading with headless Chrome 79 (same problem with Canary) on Windows (both 32 bits and 64 bits versions).

Here's an example with Google Fonts:

```
chrome.exe --headless --disable-gpu https://fonts.google.com
```

Using the DevTools inspector, I get this error:

[image: Font face error with Headless Chrome 79 on Windows]

There is no problem with non-headless mode.

I get this font face loading problem with each page which uses Google Fonts.

I wasn't able to reproduce this error on Bionic.

I'm totally stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just stumbled over the same issue today.

Adding the following parameter solved that issue for me:

```
--virtual-time-budget=10000
```

It will tell Chrome to at wait (max. 10000ms) for all pending network request.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53690355/4045505

Comment: Very interesting, thanks a lot!

Comment: Tried 20 switches, and this was the one that solved the issue. The issue only sporadicly showed on same machines.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed missing fonts for Latex math equations in R Quarto documents