# Problem with fonts on generated PDF via chrome headless

Tags: pdf-generation, google-chrome-headless

In my project (PHP) I used headless chrome for generate PDF from HTML file. I used this command:

google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf-no-header --no-margins --print-to-pdf=example.pdf example.html

It works perfect, but for some reasons on some result pdf no any text. Links to PDF + HTML file: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/Jw3GlM_h3Zf_QA

It looks like this:
[image: pdf font problem]

Command output:

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/srv/projects//.local’: Permission denied | touch: cannot touch ‘/srv/projects//.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list’: No such file or directory | [1019/033555.836260:ERROR:nss_util.cc(53)] Failed to create /srv/projects/.pki/nssdb directory. | [1019/033556.904768:INFO:headless_shell.cc(619)] Written to file /srv/projects/aa/api/reports/19_10_2021/B258C488D7ED8AF8/90589391634614272.pdf

What I can to do with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of others landing here on an old issue:-

I had no problem with headless printing that file but you are adding a switch that is not known (--no-margins) and not adding ones that may help such as.

```
google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --no-pdf-header-footer --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --print-to-pdf=example.pdf example.html
```

[image]

other switches that can help avoid runtime problems are `--disable-extensions --disable-popup-blocking --disable-checker-imaging` and for some debugging you can try  `--enable-logging`

however the error message implies it is a `mkdir: cannot create directory` permissions problem unrelated to chrome or headless printing

Answer (score 0):

This might be a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59661819/headless-chrome-79-does-not-load-fonts-from-google-fonts-on-windows) about missing fonts when printing to PDF from Chrome Headless, in which case, the solution is to give more time to the process adding the following flag tot he command: `--virtual-time-budget=10000`